# Yugioh: Sacrifice a field card to destroy target monster

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Is there a Yugioh card with the effect (activated on the field) that you can discard a card in your hand and/or one you control to target another card on the field and destroy it?  This would, in theory, be nice to couple with Master Hyperion -- because you could then use Master Hyperion's effect to send the card recently put in the graveyard to the banished area to resolve Hyperion's effect.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Fairy-type cards or cards in general? There are quite a few which don't work with Hyperion, though.

Answer (score 4):

Snipe Hunter is your guy. He can discard as many cards from your hand as you like to target any card on the field. Then you roll a die and if it's 2, 3, 4 or 5, the card is destroyed.

A good once-per-turn option is Scrap Dragon. He allows you to target one card on each side of the field which then get destroyed.

Spell and Trap wise, there's Raigeki Break, Phoenix Wing Wind Blast and Dark Core. There might be more of them, see my advice below.

Other than that, there are mainly only specific cards which won't work with Hyperion, such as Exiled Force or Chiron the Mage. That kind of card isn't that rare.
You might want to look for Cards that destroy cards on the field on the wikia. Most of them have a drawback, which is often discarding or Tributing cards.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest the monster card effect called [Exiled Force](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exiled_Force)?

> You can Tribute this card to **target 1 monster on the field; destroy that target**.

Another option could be the trap card called [Raigeki Break](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Raigeki_Break)

> **Discard 1 card, then target 1 card on the field; destroy it**.

This last one card matches with your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this list to [Send cards from your Deck to the Graveyard](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Sends_from_Deck_to_Graveyard) or this list to [Send cards from your Deck to the Graveyard at a cost](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Sends_from_Deck_to_Graveyard_for_cost)

there are also cards like [Card Destruction](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Destruction) or [Graceful Charity](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Graceful_Charity) might come in handy, while the first can wipe out your entire hand if you have a hand full of light type fairies, the second can allow you the chance in drawing 2 and sending them right into the grave yard.

Your best bet is to find cards which allow you to draw a new card at the same time as discarding, if they draw before discard then you have a chance in drawing a light type fairy

your other option is to stock up on weaker ones and use them as fodder in Defense Mode, even if your opponent works out what your doing they have no choice but to wipe them out unless they have cards which can deal direct damage